# How to ensure that the Select and Subscribe methods are called in sync in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am testing trying to test RX and creating Stream() which provides two events 1 second apart.

```
private IObservable<string> Stream()
{
    return Observable.Create<string>
    (
        (IObserver<string> observer) =>
        {
            observer.OnNext("a");
            observer.OnNext("b");
            observer.OnCompleted();         
            return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
        }
    );
}

  _refreshFiberStream =
    Stream()
    .SubscribeOn(schedulerProvider.EventLoop) 
    .Select(DoCalc)
    .ObserveOn(schedulerProvider.Dispatcher)
    .Subscribe(Update);
```

And ScheduleProvider

```
 public sealed class SchedulerProvider : ISchedulerProvider
  {
    public IScheduler Dispatcher
    {
      get { return DispatcherScheduler.Current; }
    }

    public IScheduler EventLoop
    {
      get { return new EventLoopScheduler(); }
    }
    // ...
  }
```

I see that DoCalc methods gets called twice for each input followed by Update method called twice, DoCalc, DoCalc, Update, Update. Instead I am trying to enfore sequence that DoCalc method followed by Update method. Repeating the sequence for second input, so the second input can build on top of the results from first input, DoCalc, Update, DoCalc, Update

Any thoughts

Comment: Can you provide the code for `scheduleProvider`?  If I remove the `SubscribeOn` and `ObserveOn` lines, then I see your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would follow the pattern of putting your SubscribeOn/ObserveOn pair right before your final Subscribe method. This will just save you a lot of hair-pulling.

```
_refreshFiberStream = Stream()
    .Select(DoCalc)
    //Always in this pattern
    .SubscribeOn(schedulerProvider.EventLoop) //SubscribeOn right before ObserveOn (or before Subscribe if no ObserveOn is used)
    .ObserveOn(schedulerProvider.Dispatcher)  //ObserveOn right before Subscribe
    .Subscribe(Update);                       //Subscribe Last
```

Next if I recreate your sample and add in the missing code, I get the correct/expected output.

```
void Main()
{
    var els = new EventLoopScheduler();
    var dispatcher = new EventLoopScheduler();

    Stream()
        .SubscribeOn(els) //TODO: Move to line just before ObserveOn
        .Select(DoCalc)
        .ObserveOn(dispatcher)
        .Subscribe(Update); 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private IObservable<string> Stream()
{
    return Observable.Create<string>
    (
        (IObserver<string> observer) =>
        {
            observer.OnNext("a");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            observer.OnNext("b");
            observer.OnCompleted();         
            return Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Observer has unsubscribed"));
        }
    );
}
private string DoCalc(string val)
{
    val.Dump("DoCalc()");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return val;
}
private void Update(string val)
{
    val.Dump("Update()");
}
```

So can you re-post your full sample code with output. Do this either as a unit test, console app or LinqPad sample.

To guess your next question, which may be: how can I use the values from the projection (`Select`) from a previous value to help calculate the next value? Use the `Scan` method if you want a [running set of calculations](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#BuildYourOwn) alternatively use the `Aggregate` method if you only want the final result and not each value as it is calculated.

Comment: Can you remove Thread.Sleep in DoCalc and try running. And you would get DoCalc, DoCalc followed by Update, Update instead of DoCalc, Update, DoCalc, Update

Comment: Correct. This is what I would expect. The Create delegate is being run on the `SubscribeOn` scheduler and will `OnNext` directly to the `Select` handler which is `DoUpdate`. The result of the `DoUpdate` is the result projection of the sequence. These values are then scheduled to the final subscription handler. If you need these values to serialize, then don't force two sets of scheduling, or do what ever you are doing to in the Update, in another Select projection.

Comment: If you can further explain why you need this maybe I could provide better help. e.g. Why is it a problem that these overlap?